# How to prevent unnecessary API call in React useEffect?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-hooks, reselect

My `HomeScreen` component contains an API call to get the current user. Is there a way to have it make an API call ONLY if the user has changed. As of now, if I move away from the screen and then come back it makes an API call and displays the loader which I think is not perfect user experience not to mention that the API request is completely redundant since the user has not changed.

```
useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(userRequest({ userId, userRole }))
}, [dispatch, userId, userRole])
```

I also tried to use `reselect` to get the `userId` and the `userRole` from `Redux` and wrapper my `HomeScreen` component in `React.memo` but it seems to get rerendered every time

Here is how I get the data from `Redux`

```
const userId = useSelector(selectUserId)
const userRole = useSelector(selectUserRole)
```

My selectors:

```
const loginInfoSelector = (state: AppStateType) => state.loginInfo

export const selectUserId = createSelector(
  loginInfoSelector,
  (loginInfo) => loginInfo.id
)
export const selectUserRole = createSelector(
  loginInfoSelector,
  (loginInfo) => loginInfo.role
)
```

Comment: `if(!userExists(userId,userRole)) { fetch() }` ? Using `reselect` and `memo` has nothing to do with your API calls... Put a condition on your API request

Comment: Why would you want to add `dispatch` to the dependencies of `useEffect()`?

Comment: Check if you have data for the user. If not then only make the call. Thats the best way to limit the API calls. reselect and memo whole help much with the api call.

Answer (score 1):

I would try to remove `dispatch` from dependency array as:

```
useEffect(() => {
   dispatch(userRequest({ userId, userRole }))
}, [userId, userRole])
```

In this way it's only triggered once `userId` or `userRole` are changing.